# How to loop ip range in cidr format in a text file

Tags: bash, perl, loops

i just stumbles across this script http://paste.ubuntu.com/10416480/ that takes a single iprange in cidr format and looks for open dns.Thats cool.Am wondering how it can be modified to take ipranges in a text file.Such that when its done with one iprange it goes to the next in a fast manner,just like the program is being fed one iprange at a time thanks

Comment: Please include the part of the code you need help with and explain what it does, what you changed, and how that fails for you.

Comment: the whole code is here  http://paste.ubuntu.com/10416480/ . i would like the code to take ranges from a text file . currently the code takes one range at a time and it has to be input manually. that's very time consuming

Comment: I don't think your question is unclear but you should review the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help) section, in particular http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: the question is clear. the program is  a perl script that take a single iprange and scans for open resolvers.now i am wondering how the script can be modified to take ipranges from a text file such that when its done with one iprange it moves to the next in the list.i feel am repeating but its okay for clarity. anybody can help?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your aim is to run the script for a large number of IP ranges. Based on that assumption, there are two ways to solve the problem - either you can modify the script, or write a wrapper over it to do what you want. I'll suggest writing a shell script which wraps over the existing Perl code:

```
#!/bin/bash

# the filename is passed as the first argument. It has one IP range per line
infile=$1

while read iprange
do
    # dostuff.pl should be replaced by the perl script
    dostuff.pl "$iprange"
done < "$infile"
```

You can save the above text in a file like `dostuff.sh` and use that instead of the Perl script directly.

Comment: thanks for the reply.so on my command terminal i should write ./dostuff.sh  textwithipranges.txt  . when i do that i get the error 
  ) doesn't look like a valid IP range

Comment: To debug this, try running `bash -x dostuff.sh textwithipranges.txt`. It'll show you what bash is doing at each step, so you can validate if the Perl script is being passed an incorrect IP range.

Comment: okay . i think it was my fault.the text file now has ip ranges correctly formated and it working nice. thanks for the help

Comment: when i run the bash script all is good and i get the output for instance : !!! Got answer from 10.2.3.40 – possible open resolver! . so i ask how can i just print the ip address using grep or awk

Comment: Try using `grep -o` with a regex to detect IP addresses